# Plural acronym verb form: "PGCs stand for" vs. "PGCs stands for"

Tags: grammaticality, verb-forms, verb-usage

Is it right to say:

> PGCs stand**s** for primordial germ cells.

*PGCs* is a plural, so is it correct to use the singular verb form *stands* with it?

Comment: As a note, when introducing an acronym, it's generally easier to read the sentence if you phrase it as "Bob researched primordial germ cells (PCGs)".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's more common to give the meaning of an acronym in singular form:

> PGC stands for primordial germ cell.

If you've given this definition, it's obvious to readers that *PGCs* is the plural.

---

If you were to give the definition of "PGCs," you would still use the singular form of the verb:

> PGCs stands for primordial germ cells.

This is because the subject is the acronym "PGCs," not the primordial germ cells themselves. For example, the sentence could be reworded to more clearly show that it is the acronym that is the subject:

> The acronym "PGCs" stands for primordial germ cells.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the plural of the abbreviation *PGC* would be pronounced *pee-gee-sees* while the abbreviation *PGCs* would be pronounced *pee-gee-see-ess*. Also, *PCG* is an abbreviation, not an acronym (the difference is that you pronounce it by naming the letters, rather than treating them as spelling a word—which you could never do with *PCG*).

Comment: Could you cite a book/ an authentic website putting some light on this matter?